# getdate() performance issue sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a table with fallowing columns

```
symbol |market| bid_price | ask_price | update_time
------- ------ ----------- ----------- ------------
ABC        US     123.00     675.00         20012-09-10 4:24:32.986
CDE        SG     456.00     545.00         20012-09-10 4:26:32.986
```

And my application calling a SP for update this table.

```
update price_tbl 
set bid_price=@bid_price, ask_price=@ask_price, update_time = getdate() 
where market = @market and symbol = @symbol
```

But my application calling more than 1000 updates per second. so this SP not fast enough to update the table. I checked and found getdate() function is the bottleneck. but this system running with  sql server 2000.

1. Can I use any other method to update time other than getdate() Any
2. other proposal for increase performance of this update.

FYI: this price_tbl having around 2000 records.

---

Eddied with test result.

Table Definition
..........................................................................................

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GLDPrice](
    [Company_code] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Symbol] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SymbolA] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [SymbolB] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Market] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ExchangeCode] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Remark] [char](6) NULL,
    [Last_done] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Change] [numeric](19, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Open_Price] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Closing_Price] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Buy_Price] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Sell_Price] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Day_High] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Day_Low] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [Time_done] [char](5) NULL,
    [Cumm_vol] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Buy_quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Sell_quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Per_Change] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GLDBid] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GLDAsk] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GlobalGLDBid] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GlobalGLDAsk] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GLDBuyLastDone] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GLDSellLastDone] [numeric](19, 8) NULL,
    [GLDBuyLDUptTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [GLDSellLDUptTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GLDPrice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Company_code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GLDPrice] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_GLDPrice_SymbolA]  DEFAULT (' ') FOR [SymbolA]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GLDPrice] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_GLDPrice_Last_done]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Last_done]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GLDPrice] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UpdateTime]
GO
```

SP with getdate()
..........................................................................................

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_test_one]      
 @Symbol varchar(10),      
 @Market varchar(5),       
 @BuyPrice money,      
 @SellPrice money,      
 @LastPrice money,      
 @High  money,      
 @Low  money      

AS      
DECLARE @GLDBidPrice money      
DECLARE @GLDAskPrice money      
DECLARE @GlobalGLDBid  money      
DECLARE @GlobalGLDAsk  money      
DECLARE @GLDBidAdjust money      
DECLARE @GLDAskAdjust money      
DECLARE @GlobalBidAdjust money      
DECLARE @GlobalAskAdjust money    

SELECT @GLDBidPrice = @BuyPrice + 5      
SELECT @GLDAskPrice = @SellPrice + 5      
SELECT @GlobalGLDBid = @BuyPrice + 5      
SELECT @GlobalGLDAsk = @SellPrice + 5

UPDATE dbo.GLDprice      
SET Buy_price = @BuyPrice,      
Sell_price = @SellPrice,      
GLDBid = @GLDBidPrice,      
GLDAsk = @GLDAskPrice,      
Day_high = @High,      
Day_Low = @Low,      
GlobalGLDBid = @GlobalGLDBid,      
GlobalGLDAsk = @GlobalGLDAsk,    
UpdateTime=GetDate(),
Last_Done = @LastPrice    
WHERE  Symbol = @symbol AND Market = @Market
```

SP without getdata()
............................................................................................

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_test_two]      
 @Symbol varchar(10),      
 @Market varchar(5),       
 @BuyPrice money,      
 @SellPrice money,      
 @LastPrice money,      
 @High  money,      
 @Low  money      

AS      
DECLARE @GLDBidPrice money      
DECLARE @GLDAskPrice money      
DECLARE @GlobalGLDBid  money      
DECLARE @GlobalGLDAsk  money      
DECLARE @GLDBidAdjust money      
DECLARE @GLDAskAdjust money      
DECLARE @GlobalBidAdjust money      
DECLARE @GlobalAskAdjust money    

SELECT @GLDBidPrice = @BuyPrice + 5      
SELECT @GLDAskPrice = @SellPrice + 5      
SELECT @GlobalGLDBid = @BuyPrice + 5      
SELECT @GlobalGLDAsk = @SellPrice + 5

UPDATE dbo.GLDprice      
SET Buy_price = @BuyPrice,      
Sell_price = @SellPrice,      
GLDBid = @GLDBidPrice,      
GLDAsk = @GLDAskPrice,      
Day_high = @High,      
Day_Low = @Low,      
GlobalGLDBid = @GlobalGLDBid,      
GlobalGLDAsk = @GlobalGLDAsk,    
Last_Done = @LastPrice    
WHERE  Symbol = @symbol AND Market = @Market
```

Test Script
...........................................................................................

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @start datetime


SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @count = 0;
set @start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

WHILE (@count < 10000)
BEGIN
SET @count = @count + 1
EXEC    [dbo].[update_test_one]
        @Symbol = N'I9T',
        @Market = N'SG',
        @BuyPrice = 0.8,
        @SellPrice = 0.8,
        @LastPrice = 0.8,
        @High = 0.8,
        @Low = 0.8

EXEC    [dbo].[update_test_one]
        @Symbol = N'0001.HK',
        @Market = N'HK',
        @BuyPrice = 112,
        @SellPrice = 112,
        @LastPrice = 112,
        @High = 112,
        @Low = 112
END

print 'Test 01 : ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEDIFF(millisecond,@start,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

SET @count = 0;
set @start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHILE (@count < 10000)
BEGIN
SET @count = @count + 1
EXEC    [dbo].[update_test_two]
        @Symbol = N'I9T',
        @Market = N'SG',
        @BuyPrice = 0.8,
        @SellPrice = 0.8,
        @LastPrice = 0.8,
        @High = 0.8,
        @Low = 0.8

EXEC    [dbo].[update_test_two]
        @Symbol = N'0001.HK',
        @Market = N'HK',
        @BuyPrice = 112,
        @SellPrice = 112,
        @LastPrice = 112,
        @High = 112,
        @Low = 112
END

print 'Test 02 : ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEDIFF(millisecond,@start,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
GO
```

Result:

```
Test 01 : 82310
Test 02 : 12176
```

Result with reverse test.

```
Test 02 : 15413
Test 01 : 81636
```

Comment: *How* did you determine that `GETDATE()` is the bottleneck?

Comment: have you tried passing the time also from front end?

Comment: Does price_tbl have an index on 'market' and 'symbol'?

Comment: Please provide the execution plan for the query. Also if you are doing 1,000 updates per second you may be experiencing blocking from other concurrent updates or periodic slowdowns related to (as an example) transaction log auto growth. Unfortunately on 2000 not as easy to investigate the root cause as for later versions.

Comment: @Damien - first it took 10 second to execute SP 2000 times then I Removed  the getdate() function from SP and just ran `update price_tbl 
set bid_price=@bid_price, ask_price=@ask_price
where market = @market and symbol = @symbol`
then it took 3 seconds

Comment: @JoeGJoseph - So your idea is "application date recover time" < "sql server date recover time" is that true?

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight - no any index in this table

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya - RE: Your response to Damien did you just try one batch? I would suspect that any difference you saw may have been a fluke. If it is consistently repeatable your end please provide table structure and full stored procedure definition (both versions) and code you were using to test so we can see the test methodology and if anyone else can reproduce.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya - did you properly benchmark this by flushing buffers between those two runs?

Comment: Can you show the table definition and indexes please?

Comment: Just an aside, you should really be using `getutcdate()` instead of getdate() because it costs you nothing to use UTC to begin with but lots to change it later if you ever need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me `Test 01 : 266`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_test_one]            
     @Symbol varchar(10),      
     @Market varchar(5),       
     @BuyPrice money,      
     @SellPrice money,      
     @LastPrice money,      
     @High  money,      
     @Low  money    

    AS            
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE P    
    SET P.Buy_price = @BuyPrice,            
    P.Sell_price = @SellPrice,            
    P.GLDBid = @BuyPrice + C.BidRate,            
    P.GLDAsk = @SellPrice + isnull(C.AskRate,0),            
    P.Day_high = @High,            
    P.Day_Low = @Low,            
    P.GlobalGLDBid = @BuyPrice+ isnull(C.BidRateGlobal,0),            
    P.GlobalGLDAsk = @SellPrice+isnull(C.AskRateGlobal,0),          
    P.UpdateTime=CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120),
    P.Last_Done = @LastPrice     
    FROM dbo.GLDPrice AS P    
    INNER JOIN DBO.GLDContract AS C
    ON P.Company_code=C.Company_code  
    WHERE  P.Symbol = @symbol AND P.Market = @Market 

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 3):

> I checked and found getdate() function is the bottleneck

I can absolutely 100% guarantee that your finding is wrong. The performance problem is by no means `getdate()`. For the record, not only calling `getdate()` 1000 times is not visible in the performance, but getdate()` happens to be a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx)!

If you want to troubleshoot SQL Server performance issues, follow a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) or follow the [Performance Troubleshooting Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx).

My bet is that the performance problem is here:

```
where market = @market and symbol = @symbol
```

You're either missing an appropriate index on `(market, symbol)` or the type of the parameters `@market` and/or `@symbol` are incorrect and, due to [data type precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), cause table scans instead of index seeks.

Comment: first it took 10 second to execute SP 2000 times then I Removed the getdate() function from SP and just ran `update price_tbl set bid_price=@bid_price, ask_price=@ask_price where market = @market and symbol = @symbol` then it took 3 seconds

Comment: cold run vs. warm run. Add the required index before discussing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't presented a benchmark, I thought I'd do one, and then everyone can poke holes in the methodology. Hence CW :-):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
go
create table prices (symbol char(3) not null,market char(2) not null,
    bid_price decimal(18,4) not null,ask_price decimal(18,4) not null,
    update_time datetime not null,
    constraint PK_prices PRIMARY KEY (symbol,market)
)
GO
create table #Digits (d int not null)
insert into #Digits (d)
select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
create table #Numbers (n int not null)
insert into #Numbers (n)
select d1.d * 10000 + d2.d * 1000 + d3.d * 100 + d4.d * 10 + d5.d
from #Digits d1,#Digits d2,#Digits d3,#Digits d4,#Digits d5

insert into prices (symbol,market,bid_price,ask_price,update_time)
select
    CHAR(65+n/(26*26)) + CHAR(65+((n/26)%26)) + CHAR(65+(n%26)),m.market,n,n+5,GETDATE()
from
    #Numbers nu,
    (select 'US' as market union all select 'SG') m
where nu.n < (26*26*26)
go
drop table #Digits
drop table #Numbers
```

The above sets us up with a table with ~30000 rows (so, more than you say you have). It also warms up the table, because every row has been recently accessed. I can't remember what invocations will clear this out for SQL Server 2000, but it ought to be fair enough to now run the tests in either order.

```
declare @market char(2)
declare @symbol char(3)
declare @price1 decimal(18,4)
declare @price2 decimal(18,4)
declare @start datetime
declare updates cursor local static for select symbol,market,bid_price,ask_price from prices
open updates

set @start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

fetch next from updates into @symbol,@market,@price1,@price2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    update prices 
    set bid_price=@price2, ask_price=@price1
    where market = @market and symbol = @symbol

    fetch next from updates into @symbol,@market,@price1,@price2
end
close updates
deallocate updates

print '"FAST" took ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEDIFF(millisecond,@start,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
go
declare @market char(2)
declare @symbol char(3)
declare @price1 decimal(18,4)
declare @price2 decimal(18,4)
declare @start datetime
declare updates cursor local static for select symbol,market,bid_price,ask_price from prices
open updates

set @start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

fetch next from updates into @symbol,@market,@price1,@price2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    update prices 
    set bid_price=@price2, ask_price=@price1,update_time = GETDATE()
    where market = @market and symbol = @symbol

    fetch next from updates into @symbol,@market,@price1,@price2
end
close updates
deallocate updates

print '"SLOW" took ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEDIFF(millisecond,@start,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
go
drop table prices
```

The only difference between these two cursor loops is that the second one does the `GETDATE()` based update to `update_time`, whereas the first performs no update to this column (as you indicated you'd done in your testing).

On my machine(*) , I get the result:

```
"FAST" took 20503
"SLOW" took 20436
```

Which indicates that the "slow" method, using `GETDATE()`, was 0.1 seconds faster.

(*)

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039 (Intel X86)
>
> May  3 2005 23:18:38
>
> Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
>
> Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: hi Damien, I edited my question with appending test result. could you check?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya - I might be able to try, if you can add the table definitions to your question as well (I see several new columns involved). You may be able to try a repeat run yourself - what happens if you reverse the order of the two tests?

Comment: Table definition and reverse test result added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime;
SELECT @CurrentDate = getdate();

update price_tbl 
set bid_price=@bid_price, ask_price=@ask_price, update_time = @CurrentDate
where market = @market and symbol = @symbol
```

See if this works

Comment: You sure of that? I think it will be execute every time loop all the records in the batch, but if you pull it out, then it only execute once, isn't it?

Comment: @simon - logically what is the deferment between this method and my method?

Comment: @SimonWang: If its in a loop then you may be right.. but the SP is executed 1000 time in a second as per the question

Comment: @Simon - In my case no loop involve here. if the market price change. my application call this SP with new prices. as you all know market prices change so frequently. So for 2000 symbols more than 1000 updates per second is typical.

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario like this and i gave a solution like this,
I passed the date time as the parameter from the front end to SP. otherwise if you want to handle in the SP itself you can go for this, like

```
DECLARE @time DATETIME
Set @time = getdate()
```

and you can pass it to your argument list, but note that we wont get the exact milliseconds in some case we handle that too in front end. because all record will have same present time with only different second value.

In front end yo can pass the value as,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Comment: Actually your idea is OK logically. but I'm trying to handle it inside the DB Server. So your idea is
"application date recover time" < "sql server date recover time"
is that true?

Comment: For every loop you have to get the values from front end means it takes so much time... i thought date time is one time variable...